# OWASP ZAP - Unable to intercept SOAP API requests

Tags: proxy, soap-client, client-certificates, zap, penetration-testing

I am new to the ZAP and trying to pen test XML(SOAP) services. I already have Java based regression tests for the SOAP and trying to proxy them through ZAP, but unable to do so.

I am looking for some guidance as how to successfully use my regression tests to perform security testing on SOAP services using ZAP?

***Details:***

I add following parameters to Java in my regression tests so that they may successfully connect to SOAP services:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/standalone/configuration/app.keystore"); // certificate
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "somepassword"); // password
```

ZAP is starting up with following command-line and able to intercept other browser calls proxying through localhost:8888:

```
zap.bat -host localhost -port 8888 -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config api.key=12345 -config connection.timeoutInSecs=60
```

But when I try to run regression tests with following proxy settings, they completely ignore ZAP as proxy and run just fine with or without ZAP server running:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");          
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost");     System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

Then I added SOCKs proxy settings in regression tests:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "8888");
```

Now, I get following error in tests:

```
16:52:00.623 [main] ERROR com.dummy.client.ServiceClient - java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused: connect
java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:428) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at com.dummy.client.AppHttpClient.request(AppHttpClient.java:83) ~[appc3-ws-client-12.00.01.jar:?]
    at com.dummy.stub.ServiceStub.authorization(ServiceStub.java:89) ~[appc3-ws-client-12.00.01.jar:?]
    at com.dummy.client.ServiceClient.doAuthorization(ServiceClient.java:367) ~[appc3-ws-client-12.00.01.jar:?]
    at com.dummy.client.ServiceClient.doAuthorization(ServiceClient.java:397) ~[appc3-ws-client-12.00.01.jar:?]
    at com.dummy.ca.reusable.WebService.authorization(WebService.java:65) ~[main/:?]
    at com.dummy.ca.reusable.WebService.Change(WebService.java:657) ~[main/:?]
    at com.dummy.ca.StepsLibrary.T3_Poster.changeDevice(T3_Poster.java:238) ~[main/:?]
    at com.dummy.ca.stepDefinations.PosterUpdatePD.change(PosterUpdatePD.java:219) ~[main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66) ~[cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24) ~[cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:44) ~[cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59) ~[cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:44) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:63) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:102) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:71) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:131) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86) ~[cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87) [cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:78) [cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:33) [cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

And ZAP command-line shows below Socket timeout warning, whenever I fire regression:

```
6862 [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader - Initializing Tips and Tricks
6868 [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader - Initializing Allows to fuzz WebSocket messages.
7259 [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] INFO  org.zaproxy.zap.extension.callback.ExtensionCallback - Started callback server on 0.0.0.0:61252
7260 [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] INFO  org.zaproxy.zap.extension.keyboard.ExtensionKeyboard - Initializing keyboard shortcuts
9203 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control - New Session
9212 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control - Create and Open Untitled Db
9219 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache commit start
9221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache commit end
9231 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - Database closed
9398 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache open start
9402 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache commit start
9407 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache commit end
9408 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  hsqldb.db.HSQLDB379AF3DEBD.ENGINE - dataFileCache open end
40538 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] WARN  org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread - Socket timeout while reading first message.
50575 [ZAP-ProxyThread-2] WARN  org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread - Socket timeout while reading first message.
60604 [ZAP-ProxyThread-3] WARN  org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread - Socket timeout while reading first message.
70630 [ZAP-ProxyThread-4] WARN  org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread - Socket timeout while reading first message.
80679 [ZAP-ProxyThread-5] WARN  org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread - Socket timeout while reading first message.
```

Comment: What makes you think these settings will work? You are using the `AppHttpClient` not the java client. Perhaps you can check the docs for the Apache client?

Comment: The other thing you should do is make a small program to see if you understand how to connect to the socks proxy from java. You have way too much code for anyone who doesn't already know what to do to debug the problem. So help yourself and make the problem smaller.

Comment: Well if ZAP timed out it was trying to process something but didn’t get a response before the timeout was exceeded. Looks like it’s either an environmental or target issue, NOT a ZAP issue.